# How to read in multiple files in a folder using paste in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, paste, read.table

The function  sort of runs. It outputs a list of years instead of reading in the 104 files on my computer. I have tried setting  knitr as well, and code listed below in the comments. I am open to ideas about the inside of the function(year="all"), but my homework requires that we use the paste function.

````
    setwd("C:/Users/Sarah/Downloads/names-full-datasets/names-full-datasets")
    library(purrr)
    baby.names <- function(year="all"){
    if(year!="all"){cnames <- read.table(paste("yob",year,".txt", sep = 
     ""),header = FALSE, 
    sep = ",", col.names = c("Name","Sex","Count"))
    cnames$year <- year
      }
     else
    {
    cnames <- lapply(1910:2013, baby.names)
    ldply(cnames)
    }    
    }
   yall <- baby.names()`
```
````

Comment: So far as I can tell, the default value of the `year` argument in your function is "all". But the function only sets the working directory if the value is not "all". On top of that, you already set the directory outside of the function. I'd suggest searching this site for other solutions, there are many similar questions with good answers.

Comment: This is for homework, so my teacher asked us to set the function to all. Then run it so that it runs all years. Since it is homework, I have to keep it within a function for the purpose of getting full credit, even though there are easier ways to do this.

Comment: But you should write your function so that it works whether or not `year` is set to `"all"`. The working directory is the same whether or not `year` is set to `"all"`, so at least put the `setwd()` *before* the `if()`, not inside it.

Comment: Sorry I had fixed that on the original code, but  pasted the wrong version

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer 
I just needed to add return. Thanks for all the help!

```
library(plyr)
setwd("C:/Users/Sarah/Downloads/names-full-datasets/names-full-datasets")
baby.names <- function(year="all"){
  if(year!="all"){cnames <- read.table(paste("yob", year, ".txt", sep = ""), header = FALSE, sep = ",", col.names = c("Name","Sex","Count"))
cnames$year <- year 
return(cnames) 
  }
  else
  {
    cnames1 <- lapply(1910:2013, baby.names)
    ldply(cnames1)
  }

}
```